# Mongodb: dynamically exclude fields from update function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the following Meteor method:

```
  'updateDoc': function (doc, obj) {
      Movies.update(
        {_id: doc},
        {$set: {field1: obj.key1, field2: obj.key2, field3: obj.key3} }
      );
    },
```

The problem is that `obj` creates dynamically and, for example, may not include `key2`. Is there any way to exclude appropriate field from update function to avoid overwriting to null in that case?